# Error with the result of an activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an Activity(1) that opens another Activity(2) for a result and that result is saved with `SharedPreferences` and it will be displayed when the activity starts again.
But when 2 returns the result and 1 must restart, the phone says that the app is not responding.
This is my `OnActivityResult()` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data.getExtras().containsKey("score")) {
            a +=Integer.valueOf(data.getStringExtra("score")); 
        }
        while(a>0){
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("score", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("intScore", a);
        editor.commit();
        }
    }
```

And I have this in the `OnCreate()` method:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("score", 0);
        txtScore.setText(" "+prefs.getInt("intScore", 0));
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

in your `onActivityResult` check

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE)
{

 // then your statements
}
```

and in the `activity2` don't forget to `setResult()`

Comment: i still have the same problem!